# Add CSS-class with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm having a WordPress-installation which I want to use for a one-page-site. I'm getting all the content with the 'query_post' array. For each page-section, it creates a div with the id #content.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
            <div id="main" class="m-all">

                <h2><?php the_field('headline') ?></h2>

                <div class="sidebar"><?php the_field('sidebar') ?></div>

                <div class="main-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

What I want to do now is to add a specific ID to each page-section depending on the order. Something like

```
<div id="content section-1">...</div>
<div id="content section-2">...</div>
<div id="content section-3">...</div>
```

and so on. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your code: id instead of classes ;)

Comment: In addition to the above, you should use a `counter`

Comment: Oh my god! the content id is being duplicated. :O :O

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts` unless you need to break page functionalities on purpose :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="content section-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
            <div id="main" class="m-all">

                <h2><?php the_field('headline') ?></h2>

                <div class="sidebar"><?php the_field('sidebar') ?></div>

                <div class="main-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This will be work also

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC'); ?>
```

```
<div id="content section-<?php echo $i++; ?>">
    <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
            <div id="main" class="m-all">

                <h2><?php the_field('headline') ?></h2>

                <div class="sidebar"><?php the_field('sidebar') ?></div>

                <div class="main-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First logically one element should have only one id. and since you are repeating whole id="content", i suggest you to better add class instead and you can add wrapper of id="content". and for getting id you can simple use the_ID(); that should work. so the code should look like

```
<div id="content">

    <?php query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC'); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div id="inner-content<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="wrap cf">

          <div id="main" class="m-all">

                    <h2><?php the_field('headline') ?></h2>

                    <div class="sidebar"><?php the_field('sidebar') ?></div>

                    <div class="main-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

                </div>
        </div>

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

So now All of them will have unique id. :) Cheers!!!